# what is the json mapping to insert geo data into elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

what would be the json mapping to insert geo data into elasticsearch ??
if the sample json data as follows:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 631861455.000000, "address": "1206 UPPER", "city": "la vegas", "state": "AL", "zip_code": "15656", "OGR_GEOMETRY": "POLYGON" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -86.477551331, 32.490605650000099 ], [ -86.477637350999899, 32.4903921820001 ], [ -86.478257247, 32.490565591000099 ], [ -86.478250466, 32.490580239000103 ], [ -86.478243988, 32.490593680000096 ], [ -86.47823751, 32.490607122 ], [ -86.478231749, 32.490619100000096 ], [ -86.478224637, 32.490634065000101 ], [ -86.47821823699999, 32.490647540000097 ], [ -86.478211847999901, 32.490661035000095 ], [ -86.478205478999897, 32.490674526000099 ], [ -86.478202107999891, 32.490681666000093 ], [ -86.478199132, 32.4906880240001 ], [ -86.478192825999898, 32.490701523 ], [ -86.478186533, 32.490715047 ], [ -86.47818320899999, 32.490722209000097 ], [ -86.47818027999989, 32.490728569000098 ], [ -86.478174063, 32.490742125000097 ], [ -86.47816785099999, 32.490755654000097 ], [ -86.47816255799999, 32.490767236000096 ], [ -86.478159053999889, 32.490774513000105 ], [ -86.477551331, 32.490605650000099 ] ] ] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Geo point mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/geo-point.html).
You need to define mapping.